# Create freestyle lines like the orange outlines of selected meshes?

Tags: rendering, materials, freestyle

[image] [image] [image]

I used an emission shader, and I was wonder if that the black lines (from 3rd photo is render view) could be the same as the the orange selected lines minus the origin points (2nd photo). The first photo is just the 3d view port.